# Express app.use does not send correct fake data

Tags: javascript, express, callback, routes, faker

I was practicing Express 4.x and noticed the following:

```
app.get('/fake', function(req, res) {
  var obj = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    jsf.resolve(fakeSchema).then(function(iter) {
      obj.push(iter);
    });
  }
  res.send(obj);
});
```

So, going to that route, I get `"[ ]"`, while I was expecting to receive an array of 3 (fake) documents.

FYI, when logging each loop, I can clearly see the documents generated, even inside the array.

Any explanation?

Comment: ```jsf.resolve(fakeSchema)``` returns a promise, when you attempt to return the array, the promise may not have been resolved.

Comment: check this out. What you want is to wait untill all of the promises are resolved. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: Put `res.send(obj);` after `obj.push(iter);` line immediately

Answer (score 1):

Your jsf.resolve functiion is async so you can use `async/await` for this to perform task in sync manner.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

```
 app.get('/fake', async function(req, res) {
        var obj = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            try {
                var iter = await jsf.resolve(fakeSchema);
                obj.push(iter);
            } catch (e) {}
        }
        res.send(obj);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Although @Nishant's provided answer works, I suggest using this approach.

```js
let jsf = {};
// faking your jsf.resolve method
jsf.resolve = (param) => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(Math.random());
    }, 1000);
  })
};
let fakeSchema = {};
let obj = [];
let promises = [];
for (let i = 0; i !== 3; i++) {
  promises.push(jsf.resolve(fakeSchema).then(function (iter) {
    obj.push(iter);
  }));
}
Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
  console.log(obj);
});
```

This allows all the promises to run concurrently, imagine your `jsx.resolve` takes a long time to complete, using `await` would freeze your entire appp.

As opposed to this. Note the runtime.

```js
(async () => {
  let jsf = {};
  // faking your jsf.resolve method
  jsf.resolve = (param) => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve(Math.random());
      }, 1000);
    })
  };
  let fakeSchema = {};
  let obj = [];
  for (let i = 0; i !== 3; i++) {
    obj.push(await jsf.resolve(fakeSchema));
  }
  console.log(obj);
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

@Nishant Dixit's answer also correct! 
You can try this simple solution also, if you like :

```
app.get('/fake', function(req, res) {
  var obj = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    try {
        jsf.resolve(fakeSchema).then(function(iter) {
           obj.push(iter);
           res.send(obj);
    } catch (e) {
        res.send(e);
    }
    });
  };
});
```

Comment: In this implementation, is it ok for the server to send the obj in each iteration?